# Cron job not working using crontab linux

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron

I try to run my laravel command through cron job. But when I put my laravel command into cron job using crontab after adding in cron tab i did not see the working on cron job because my database not updated. Below is my cron tab file

```
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bi$
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTP=isnap@gmail.com
* * * * * php /home/isnap/test/api/local artisan command:trending_posts_view && /tmp/myscript.sh
```

Help to solve this issue

Comment: See @Marcin answers since it properly fixes the error. Next time try to run the full command.

Comment: For all cron related issues https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
* * * * * php /home/isnap/test/api/local/artisan command:trending_posts_view && /tmp/myscript.sh
```

(space between local and artisan replaced with slash)

Comment: can you please let me know that how i can run laravel 4 commands in through cron jobs using crontab?

Comment: @RizwanSaleem What do you mean? This is exact way how to use single command. You can add multiple entries in your crontab so you can add them in separate lines starting with stars as showed above. You can have for example 20 cron jobs (20 lines) running every minute

Comment: you are saying correct but I don't know that where i am doing mistake so that's why I ask it from you that is there is any helpful link from where i can get complete guidness may be configuration mistake i have done.